# How can I read SIP server response

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

I am using Jain SIP to send a register request to a server using `SipProvider.sendRequest(request)`.

How can I listen for the 200 OK response from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a listener and then add the litener to the sip provider

`sipProvider.addSipListener(listener);`

Here is a full example https://svn.java.net/svn/jsip~svn/trunk/src/examples/simplecallsetup/Shootist.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the netcat command and listen on the port (and ip-address) where the client is listening.
Syntax

nc -l